# Android, HTTP POST value from spinner

Tags: android, http, post, spinner

I'm trying to send data from spinner to server. This is code for spinner:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String label = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Chosen: " + label, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            tokens = new StringTokenizer(label, " ");
            time = tokens.nextToken().trim();
        }
```

So when user pick from spinner (he can choose time value(there's 15 min, 30 min, 45 min in spinner)), in `time = tokens.nextToken().trim();` i can get the time he chose. Now, i'm trying to send it to server, so my question is how to it? Will [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheHttpClient/article.html) work (2.3. Http Post) or there's a way to do it with retrofit 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your service:

```
public interface MyService{
   @FormUrlEncoded
   @POST("/time")
   Call<Response> postTime(@Field("time") String time);
}
```

Create Your Retrofit Builder

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://yourserver.com/")
    .build();

GitHubService service = retrofit.create(MyService.class);
```

Hit Your API:

```
service.postTime(time);
```

This is basic code to get you a head start. You can deep dive into Retrofit2 for more advanced features.

Comment: thanks, but i must use it wrong because it doesn't work, if i'm sending the time to `BASE_URL+"/send"` and the key is "inteval=" what should i change?

Comment: You dont have to use BASE_URL+/send beacuse base url is already now set in ur retrofit builder. Post your code so that I would know what's goin on

Comment: this is my class: http://www.codesend.com/view/dadacbd907a84a0bdd19d68507b4c7b1/, so i need to post time value from spinner to server,url for can be from http://requestb.in/ for test, but later it needs to be `MainAactivity.BASE_URL+"/send"` (base url is in mainactivity class) and key "interval=", the problem is i don't know how to set that

Comment: And your postinterface?

Comment: `public interface PostInterface {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST
    Call<Response> postTime(@Field("interval=") String time);
}`

Comment: In post interface you needto mention after @POST the url u want to hit so it will be like @POST("/send")

Comment: And the other thing is the Retrofit builder you have created should be in onCreate() of  base activity. It is a singleton object so just create once when the application loads.

Comment: so if i want to test it with url from requestb.in could i leave postinterface as it is and then in retrofit bulder replace `MainActivity.BASE_URL` with that url i got?

Comment: and where do i set the key? i figured it's in field in interface, but i'm sure about it

Comment: Here is my starter project on github download and run it you will get the idea : https://github.com/ameys/android-starter

Comment: the problem is that i'm total beginner, this is my first app and i don't know where to look, i can't figure it out

Comment: It has all error handling code which you need in actual application here is the service class https://github.com/ameys/android-starter/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/starter/rest/service and from here on button click the service is being called  https://github.com/ameys/android-starter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/starter/activity/MainActivity.java

Comment: Download this project run it and debug it from https://github.com/ameys/android-starter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/starter/activity/MainActivity.java from the button click listener

Comment: Or share your git project on git hub and i would help to get you running tomorrow because its pretty late night over here

Comment: hi, sorry it took so ong, here my project: https://github.com/mustangws/smarthome (POST is in Postavke.java)